# Error in installing Tensorflow in mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, syntax-error

I am trying to install Tenosrflow in mac using the instructions from

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

But I get a syntax error all the time when I want to import tensorflow.

I tried uninstalling protobuf and reinstalling tensorflow, but again I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/init.py",
>   line 22, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint:
>   disable=unused-import File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/init.py",
>   line 49, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 114 def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
>
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Do you know what is the solution for this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with python version 3.7 as you can also see in [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690). Apparently the cause is that `async` is a keyword in 3.7. Good news is that there also seems to be a solution:

As mentioned in the github issue: Renaming `async` to e.g. `async1` in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py` gets rid of the issue

Note:
There are multiple links inside of the github issue, also references to commits fixing 3.7. incompatabilities, so cloning the github and [installing from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) might also be an option

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It was exactly as you said. It is solved now.