# unable to import tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to use Keras but it showed mw this error :(.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## Additional information:

python version: 3.7.
Tensorflow version: 1.10.0.

Comment: There seems to be a Tensorflow compatibility issue with python 3.7. I would suggest for you to downgrade to python 3.6 instead. This thread is just a bit old but you can use it as a reference - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in installing Tensorflow in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824226/error-in-installing-tensorflow-in-mac)

Comment: Please read the reported issue and its [resolution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690) or downgrade Python.

Answer (score 0):

It was shared on Github that the issue is that `async` is a reserved keyword in python 3.7.

You can resolve this by accessing the file (in your case `C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py`) and changing all appearances of `async` to something like `async1`.

The `async` variable is to be found in line `114`, `115`, `150` and `151`.