# Syntax error "async" when importing tensorflow in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When I try and import tensorflow into my code, this error is returned:

```
Python 3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

\>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tensorflow and keras installed on my computer. How do I fix this so that it runs properly?

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in installing Tensorflow in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824226/error-in-installing-tensorflow-in-mac)

Comment: please provide the code so that users can reproduce the problem:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example